# Why is it "obvious" that the expected value of a continuous uniform distribution is (a+b)/2?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, intuition, uniform-distribution

For a continuous uniform random variable X with support on an interval [a,b], where a<b, one can always calculate the expected value, by integrating, to arrive at the value of **(a+b)/2.**

However, since, I have been, for better or worse, "corrupted" by formal mathematics, I seem to no longer trust my intuition; even worse, I seem to question even the most "obvious" mathematical conclusions, given that I have been humbled one too many times whenever I have thought things to be "obvious".

However, I keep running into the fact that it is "obviously obvious" that the expected value of a continuous uniform distribution is (a+b)/2 time and time again. Everyone I talk to, literally everyone, no matter their backgrounds, their occupations, can see this to be true. Even middle school children can see this to be true (when uniform distribution is explained in an informal way). I, however, can't. I seem to be completely oblivious to its obviousness.

**So, could someone please explain why it is "obvious" that the expected value of a continuous random variable on an interval [a,b], where a<b, is (a+b)/2?** I understand the 'why' of it all when one formally defines a uniform distribution and integrates it. But I would be grateful if someone could provide an intuitive explanation for the same, preferably through an example.

Comment: I dislike the word "obvious" but for an argument appealing to symmetry:  if $X$ is uniform on $[a,b]$, then so is $a+b-X$, and their sum is a constant.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! But the above, I guess, works for a discrete r.v. How do you demonstrate the same symmetry for a continuous r.v. as asked in the question?

Comment: What's wrong with the argument for continuous $X$? A randomly distributed *continuous* variable $X$ is uniform on $[a, b]$, and so is $a+b-X$. Then, because they follow the same distribution, $E[X]=E[a+b-X]$ and the result follows.

Comment: There’s no reason that the expected value would be closer to $a$ than to $b$. You could probably make that idea into a rigorous proof, with some work. Or just do the calculation and be like, “Yeah that’s what I would have guessed.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea: for a uniform distribution on an interval the expectation is going to be the center of the interval since the distribution is symmetric about the center.

More rigorously: if a random variable $X$ is uniform on $[-c,c]$ for some $c > 0$ then $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$. This gives $E(X) = E(-X) = -E(X)$, leading to $E(X) = 0$.

Next, if $X$ is uniform on $[-c + d, c + d]$, then we add $d$ to the above random variable, giving $E(X) = d$, the center of the interval $[-c + d, c + d]$.

If $X$ is uniform on $[a,b]$ it falls into the situation of the last paragraph: solving $ - c + d = a$ and $c + d = b$ gives $d = {a + b \over 2}$ and $c = {b - a \over 2}$. Thus here $E(X) = d = {a + b \over 2}$.

Comment: I am sorry, I just want to get this down proper. if one considers [-c+d, c+d], why should one have E(X) = d? I get it intuitively. But here we are dealing with infinite values, given that is a continuous distribution. Why should a translation by "d" imply that the expected value will be "d"? Is it simply because, all values have been equally and simultaneously increased by "d", hence the expected value will also see a concurrent increase?

Comment: It is a well-known result that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$, where $X$ and $Y$ represent variables chosen from some parameter space. In this case, we are choosing $X$ from $[-c, c]$ and choosing $Y$ from $\{d\}$. This gives us $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=0+d=d$, because obviously if the only option is $d$ the expected value of sampling is $d$.

Comment: See, this is my point: One needed to invoke linearity of expectation, and thus rely on machinery rather than intuition. But I am trying to develop my intuitive faculties. Is there anything wrong in my answer? 

Nevertheless, I still can't see how you are invoking linearity of expectation. What do you mean by choosing Y from 'd' with regards to a continuous random variable? Choosing a point in a uniformly continuous distribution will give P(X=x) = 0, right? We may only ever choose intervals, right?

Comment: @S_M  That's basically it. Adding $d$ to a random variable causes each instance of it to be increased by $d$, so the expected value will also increase by $d$. Mathematically this can be described by the identity $E(X + d) = E(X) + d$. This is proved by adding (in the discrete case) or integrating (in the continuous case) this increase by $d$ in each instance.

Comment: @S_M: I'd like to point  that linearity of expectation is very intuitive which we later prove with  machinery. Suppose in my shop I sell tea and coffee and nothing else, and if I by  past experience expect to make 500 rupees a day by selling coffee and 800 rupees a day by selling tea then I expect my total revenue for a day to be 500+800 = 1300 rupees and anyone without college education would agree with this and so this is intuitive.

Comment: Thank you all, grateful, as always!

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Thank you, Sir. I'd like to understand your example better. I have understood linearity through other examples, but I would like to understand it through your perspective. So, in your example what is E[X], E[Y], and E[X+Y]?

Comment: @S_M: Nothing more to add. I saw your response to Daniel Geyfman's comment where you mentioned that invoking linearity relies on machinery and not intuitive. So I made my comment intuitively explaining a real life situation  without using symbols or  academic concepts

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}$
$\newcommand{\mean}{\mu}$
$\newcommand{\popvar}{\sigma^2}$
$\newcommand{\cmom}{\mu}$
$\newcommand{\meanest}{\hat{\mean}}$
$\newcommand{\seqn}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}$
$\newcommand{\rvx}{x}$
$\newcommand{\xN}{N}$
$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brl}[1]{{\left.#1\right|}}$
$\newcommand{\moment}{M}$
$\newcommand{\momest}{\hat{\moment}}$
$\newcommand{\meanest}{\hat{\mean}}$
$\newcommand{\cmomest}{\hat{\cmom}}$
$\newcommand{\varest}{\hat{\var}}$
$\newcommand{\mcom}[2]{{\displaystyle\underbrace{\displaystyle#1}_{\text{#2}}}}$
$\newcommand{\indentx}{\ensuremath{\mbox{}\qquad}}$
$\newcommand{\bcoef}[2]{{#1\choose#2}}$
$\newcommand{\pE}{\mathsf{E}}$
$\newcommand{\pdf}{{\mathsf{p}}}$
$\newcommand{\intcc}[2]{{\left[#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brlr}[1]{\left.#1\right|}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{dx}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

It's a good question.
Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution $\pdf$ in the closed interval $\intcc{a}{b}$.

\begin{align*}
  \pE\brp{X}
    &\eqd \int_{x\in\R} x \pdf(x) \dx
   &&\eqd \int_{x=a}^{x=b} x \frac{1}{b-a} \dx
   &&=    \brs{\frac{1}{b-a}} \int_{x=a}^{x=b} x \dx
  \\&=    \brs{\frac{1}{b-a}} \brlr{\frac{1}{2}x^2}_{x=a}^{x=b}
   &&=    \brs{\frac{1}{b-a}} \frac{1}{2} \brp{ b^2 - a^2 }
   &&=    \brs{\frac{1}{b-a}} \frac{1}{2} \brs{ (b+a)(b-a) }
   &&=    \frac{b + a}{2}
\end{align*}

The proof states, in part, that $$\pE\brp{X}=\brs{\frac{1}{b-a}} \int_{x=a}^{x=b} x \dx$$
which implies that

1. All the values of $x$ are being summed in the interval $\intcc{a}{b}$ and
2. Each value of $x$ in $\intcc{a}{b}$ is **equally weighted** (by $\frac{1}{b-a}$).

As such, because each value is equally weighted, it is *somewhat* intuitive that

1. The interval $\intcc{a}{b}$ is like a plank with sand evenly distributed along its surface, and
2. The *balancing point* of this sand covered plank should be halfway between (or the *average* of) the two points $a$ and $b$
3. This average of $a$ and $b$ (or halfway between $a$ and $b$) is $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous random variable with density $f$, the expectation is $\int xf(x)\,dx$. This formula is exactly the calculation for the *center of mass* of a univariate mass distribution given by $f$. (Normally the calculation requires dividing by the total mass $\int f(x)\,dx$, but here this equals unity.)

If you're comfortable with an appeal to *physical* intuition, the center of mass is the *balance point* of a mass distribution. And for a uniform distribution the mass distribution balances at the center of the distribution.

Granted, the physical intuition fails when the expectation does not exist; and if $E(X)=\infty$ we get the dubious assertion that the distribution balances at infinity. But the uniform distribution has a continuous density defined over a bounded interval, so physical intuition leads to the "obvious" conclusion without resorting to an explicit integration.